# Seg Fault upon accessing malloc'd 2d array in class

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc

This is meant to be a class that contains a 2d array of chars called "map". First, I allocate [mapDimension] char*s to a char**. Then, I allocate [mapDimension] chars to each char*. I do it this way rather than the static: char map[mapDimension][mapDimension] because while that works for small numbers, once mapDimension gets above around 2500, it also segfaults. I wanted to allocate the memory on the heap rather than the stack so that I could hold more.

The last two lines in the constructor are to initialize every char in the 2d array to 0 and then set the center one to 5.

```
#define mapDimension 1000    

class Field 
{
private:
    int i;
public:
    char** map = (char**)malloc(mapDimension * sizeof(char*));
    Field()
    {
        for(i = 0; i < mapDimension; i++)
            map[i] = (char*)malloc(mapDimension * sizeof(char));
        memset(map, 0, mapDimension*mapDimension*sizeof(char));
        map[mapDimension/2][mapDimension/2] = 5;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Field field;
    return 0;
}
```

This dynamic approach also segfaults. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is really really really bad C++. Go read a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: It may be real bad C++, but it is a valid and fairly well formed question.  Why all the neg votes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    memset(map, 0, mapDimension*mapDimension*sizeof(char));
```

You are clearing `map` array (array of *pointers*), so map[x] now contains NULL. You probably should use `map[i]` in loop to clear allocated memory.

**BUT**

1. When you allocate memory you should deallocate it (there is malloc, no free visible)
2. In C++ use `new[]` and `delete[]` instead of `malloc`
3. Even better - use `std::vector<std::vector<char>>`

Comment: I can't decide if this is an answer to the question or a comment.  I suppose it depends on the interpretation of *"What am I doing wrong?"*

Comment: vector of vector of char?  not a string?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan depending what author wants to achieve. I wanted to show how to create multidim in C++ :)

Comment: @DrewDormann - true, it would be just less readable as comment... also question is the one of "please do my debugging for me"

Comment: Was the second half a resonse for me?

Comment: @Hcorg based on your comment, I would claim **that this answer should be a comment**.  It is a very helpful comment, nonetheless.  Please don't take it personally.

Comment: @DrewDormann - don't worry, I won't. As I said - I was wondering what it should be (ans/comm), but I'm still learning proper 'feels' and 'smells' of SO.

Answer (score 2):

This statement is invalid

```
memset(map, 0, mapDimension*mapDimension*sizeof(char));
```

you allocated several extents of memory not one contiguous storage area.

You have to use a loop. For example

```
    for ( i = 0; i < mapDimension; i++ ) memset( map[i], 0, mapDimension );
```

And your class has to have a destructor that to free the allocated memory.

For example

```
~Field()
{
    for( i = 0; i < mapDimension; i++ ) free( map[i] );
    free( map );
}
```

It would be better to make `mapDimension` like a static constant variable of type `size_t` instead of using a macro definition.

Take into account that in C++ you should use operator `new` instead of C function `malloc`.

Also you could simply use container `std::vector<std::string>` instead of the manually allocated arrays.

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly, it is possible to allocate your array so that you'll be able to `memset` the entire array in one shot. But for that you have to allocate the second-level memory as *one continuous memory block* and then distribute it between the rows

  ```
  Field()
  {
    char *data_memory = (char *) malloc(mapDimension * mapDimension * sizeof(char));

    for (i = 0; i < mapDimension; i++)
      map[i] = data_memory + i * mapDimension;
    ...
  }
  ```
- Secondly, if you changed your allocation approach to a "single block allocation" (as described above) then in order to `memset` the whole thing, you have to do it as follows

  ```
  memset(map[0], 0, mapDimension * mapDimension * sizeof(char));
  ```

  or

  ```
  memset(&map[0][0], 0, mapDimension * mapDimension * sizeof(char));
  ```

  Note the fist argument of `memset`.

  But if you kept to your current allocation approach, then you can forget about using `memset` on the entire array. Your array is not continuous in memory. You can't `memset` the whole thing. All you can do is `memset` each row individually

  ```
  for (i = 0; i < mapDimension; i++)
    memset(map[i], 0, mapDimension * sizeof(char));
  ```
- Thirdly, declaring `i` as a member fo the class, instead of using a local variable `i` is bad idea. Also, using in-class initializer for the frist `malloc` is a bad idea too. Also, in C++ you should prefer to use `new/new[]` over `malloc`, not even mentioning that you should prefer to use `std::vector` over manual array memory management.